# T-SQL trigger to update columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, trigger

I've been working with SQL queries for a couple of weeks and I'm trying to learn and understand from my mistakes. I have a table with two columns `IsInvisible (bit)` and `ShortName (string)` and when one is changed to update the other one also like: - if added a ~ in front of the ShortName to set `IsInvisible` to 1 and if ~ is removed to set it to 0 - if `IsInvisible` is set to 1 to add ~ in front of the ShortName and when set to 0 to remove it.

I've tried something like:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[updateInvisibility]
ON [dbo].[table]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

UPDATE t
SET IsInvisible = (CASE WHEN i.ShortName like '~%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    ShortName = (CASE WHEN i.IsInvisible = 1 AND t.ShortName NOT LIKE '~%'
                 THEN '~' + t.ShortName
                 ELSE t.ShortName
            END)
FROM table t JOIN
     inserted i
     ON t.Id = i.Id;

end
```

My problem is that when I'm updating one of the columns or both, nothing happens and I get this error:

```
Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32)
```

What am I doing wrong?

The "Allow Triggers to Fire Others" option displays "True".

Comment: Do you have any other triggers on this table?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the problem:

1. You update the table
2. It triggers the update trigger: `updateInvisibility`
3. In the trigger you update the table again so it triggers the `updateInvisibility` trigger

and then it keeps doing that so you end up triggering the trigger many times in a sort of recursive fashion without even realizing. SQL server will allow this call nesting to be 32 levels deep and then it throws this error:

> Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32)

which is pretty clear.

#### T-SQL Solution

The code-only solution is to check the nesting level and leave if bigger than 1 (1 is the first time it is called by the update):

```
IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1 RETURN;
```

Like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[updateInvisibility]
ON [dbo].[table]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1 RETURN;

    -- Do your work...
END
```

#### Alternative

As pointed out in a comment by [RBarryYoung](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/8215/rbarryyoung), you can prevent this problem in the first place by disabling recursive triggers.